# HTML disappears after submit

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have this form:

```
<div id="tudo">
    <div id="sige">
        <div id="voltar_sair">
                    <a href="ServletListarEventosInscricoesAbertas.do" id="voltar">Voltar</a>
        </div>
        <h1>SIGE - Sistema de Gerenciamento de Eventos </h1>
            <form name="form" method="post" action="" id="sige">
                <input type="hidden" name="codigoEvento" value="<%=codigoEvento%>">
                <input type="hidden" name="tela" value="<%=tela%>"> <input
                    type="hidden" id="hidden" value="<%=cpf%>">

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Consultar Eventos do Participante</legend>
                    <p>
                        <label for="cpf">CPF:</label> <input id="cpf" name="cpf" class="mascara-cpf" type="text" onblur="if(this.value != ''){ValidarCPF(this);}" value="<%=cpf%>"/>
                    </p>

                </fieldset>

                <p>
                    <input class="botoes_form" value="Consultar" id="reemitir" type="button" onClick="javascript:consultarEventosParticipante()"/>
                    <input class="botoes_form" value="Limpar" id="limpar" type="reset" onclick="$('#cpf').val()"/>
                </p>
```

And, after submit the form, the whole p with label and input(text) disappears.

What can I do to solve this?

EDIT:

```
function consultarEventosParticipante(){

    if(document.form.cpf.value == ""){
        alert("Por favor, digite o campo C.P.F.");
        return;
    }
    document.form.action="ServletInicioConsultarEventosParticipante";
    document.form.submit();
}
```

Comment: consultarEventosParticipante() is probably doing this. You did not include this code, so I can only guess.

Comment: Isn't it clearing the entire page? Because the form is submitted?

Comment: I formatted your code for you. Please don't submit ugly unformatted code

Comment: The servlet returns to this page. It shows a table bellow this form. So if the user wants to consult again, the input is disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was solved. I put the form tag inside the fieldset and the problem is gone. I did not understand the cause of it, but that was the way to fix the bug.